# jQuery preventDefault issues with .load()

Tags: jquery, tabs, preventdefault

Everytime when I click on a tab, the tab calls getPrices(). The problem is that the current class resets to the first tab every time I click. I guess that this is because I'm calling the proxy.php with load().

Edit simplifying the Q: How do I use .addClass('current') on the clicked tab after that load() is executed?

Code from foo.php

```
    function getPrices(go) {
        if(go === true) {
        $('div').load('proxy.php5').fadeIn("slow");
        $('div td').animate({
            opacity: 0.7
        }, 200);
        return false;
        }
    };


$('div ul.tab-nav li').click(function(event) {
    getPrices(true);
    $(this).parents('ul').find('li.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Code from index.php:

```
function getPrices(go) {
    if(go === true) {
        $('#spot-prices').load('proxy.php5').fadeIn("slow");
        $('#spot-prices td').animate({
            opacity: 0.7
        }, 200);
    return false;
    }
};
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    getPrices(true);
});
```

Comment: I don't get your point. Which page is you *main* page ? What does it call and what are you expecting to happen ?

Comment: See my comment below for a link

Comment: I still don't get it. The `getPrices` is defined twice, where is the HTML code, what are `#spot-prices` and `.tab-nav` elements, ... ? We need all the available informations here

Comment: There are three files. Proxy.php is used to load test.php from a different server. #spot-prices is nothing but a container for the load(). For example, when you press on the USD tab it will call getPrices() and the container will reload. When this happens the .current class gets reseted. I want to avoid that! You can find the html source here: header.se/24/valuta/test.php Thanks a lot!

Comment: To make it easy: How do I use .addClass('current') on the clicked tab after that load() is executed?

Answer (score 0):

```
    function getPrices(go) {
        if(go) {
        $('div').load('proxy.php5').fadeIn("slow");
        $('div td').animate({
            opacity: 0.7
        }, 200);
        return true;
        }
    };


$('div ul.tab-nav li').click(function(event) {
    getPrices(true);
   $('div ul.tab-nav li').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: won't work for me. see my live example here: header.se/24/valuta/valuta2.php5